# How to upload file outside of controller and not in IFormFile type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, cqrs, mediatr

I use `Mediatr` for handling commands and queries in the Application projects which was sent from the WebApi project. In the WebApi project user sends to controller `IFormFile`. To handle `IFormFile` in the Application project I have to install `aspnetcore.http.features`. But I do not want this dependency in the Application project. How can I send the user file not in IFormFile to the handler of the Application project from the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the contents of the file into a byte array and pass the byte array as a parameter to your Mediatr request.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        var fileContents = stream.ToArray();

        var result = await _mediator.Send(new YourMediatrRequest(fileContents));

        return Ok(result);
    }
}


public class YourMediatrRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<YourMediatrRequest, YourMediatrResponse>
{
    public Task<YourMediatrResponse> Handle(YourMediatrRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var fileContents = request.FileContents;
        ...more code
    }
}
```

Comment: How optimal this solution is? From CPU and memory consumption point of view